# CMake build error in Visual Studio VTR8.0

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I am trying to build VTR8.0 on Windows Visual Studio 2019.

Error:

```
    1> [CMake] -- Tatum: will support only serial execution
    1> [CMake] -- Could NOT find TBB (missing: TBB_INCLUDE_DIRS TBB_LIBRARIES) 
    1> [CMake] -- Could NOT find TBB (missing: TBB_INCLUDE_DIRS TBB_LIBRARIES) 
    1> [CMake] -- VPR: will only support serial execution
    CMake Error at abc/CMakeLists.txt:78 (extract_var):
       extract_var Function invoked with incorrect arguments for function named:
       extract_var
Performing Test C_COMPILER_SUPPORTS__-Wno-unused-but-set-variable
1> [CMake] -- Performing Test C_COMPILER_SUPPORTS__-Wno-unused-but-set-variable - Failed
1> [CMake] -- Performing Test CXX_COMPILER_SUPPORTS__-Wno-unused-but-set-variable
1> [CMake] -- Performing Test CXX_COMPILER_SUPPORTS__-Wno-unused-but-set-variable - Failed
1> [CMake] -- Performing Test CXX_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_-Wno-int-to-pointer-cast
1> [CMake] -- Performing Test CXX_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_-Wno-int-to-pointer-cast - Failed
1> [CMake] -- Performing Test CXX_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_-w
1> [CMake] -- Performing Test CXX_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_-w - Success
1> [CMake] -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

[Error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxyzU.png)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the info you've posted is insufficient to diagnose the problem. What's passed to `extract_var` in line 78 of abc/CMakeLists.txt? If you cannot tell any other way there should be a `--trace-expand` option you can use, but the output will get pretty large...

Comment: Smells like in [abc/CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/verilog-to-routing/vtr-verilog-to-routing/blob/v8.0.0/abc/CMakeLists.txt) the variable `MAKE_OUTPUT` is empty. This variable contains output of `make` invocation. Do you ever have `make` utility?

Comment: I tried the same code on Ubuntu, and it works perfectly. I don't understand the problem in Windows.